# Will delete[] with void* cause memory leak?

Tags: c++, void-pointers, delete-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it safe to delete a void pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941832/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-void-pointer)

Will the following code cause memory leak?

```
void *ptr = new long [10];
delete[] ptr; // note: ptr is a void*
```

[EDIT]
The code above will generate a warning message during compiling to specify it "undefined".
I ask this cause I'm wondering how does C++ handle memory ranges when delete[] is called.
I should change my question to make it more specified.

Will the following code cause memory leak?

```
char *ptr = (char *)(new long [10]);
delete[] ptr; // note: ptr is a char*
```

Comment: It will not compile in most of the compilers as it would not be possible for delete to know how much memory needs to be freed for a void pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Leaving `delete[]` out will cause a leak. BTW, it should be `long* ptr`. I don't think the `delete[]` will even compile with a `void*` argument.

Comment: It may compile but the results are definitely undefined.

Comment: Generally true, but the quirk here (deemphasised by the lack of mention in the text of the question): he's deleting a `void` pointer!

Comment: Yes..but it seems that g++ may let it pass, with only a warning message "warning: deleting 'void*' is undefined". Guess I should modify my question to make it more clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following program (slight modification of [this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/new/operator%20delete%5B%5D/)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

struct myclass {
  myclass() {cout <<"myclass constructed\n";}
  ~myclass() {cout <<"myclass destroyed\n";}
};

int main () {
  void * pt = new myclass[3];
  delete[] pt;

  return 0;
}
```

using g++ and got the following compilation warning:

```
leaky.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
leaky.cpp:13: warning: deleting ‘void*’ is undefined
```

And when you run it...fail!  The process dies (invalid pointer) when you attempt to delete that pointer.