# Are there real life cases when deleting an incomplete type is not an error in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings, delete-operator

Visual C++ has [C4150 warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba5dy3f2.aspx) for cases when `delete` is applied to a pointer to incomplete type.

Such cases yield undefined behavior according to the Standard. AFAIK in Visual C++ they result in default `operator delete()` function and no destructor being called which allows for numerous bugs.

Now I could have used `#prarma warning( error : 4150 )` in Visual C++ to treat that warning as error. I guess there're reasons why it is a warning and not an error by default in Visual C++.

In what real life code would I want to allow such cases? Why would I not switch that warning into a compiler error?

Comment: Does `void` count as an incomplete type? If yes, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172232/is-it-undefined-behaviour-to-delete-a-null-void-pointer) may be relevant. :)

Comment: You can never know what Microsoft meant with their products.

Comment: Perhaps a class with trivial destructor?

Comment: I vaguely recall our product team hitting a bug in an older compiler version where no warning was generated at all for this error. For production code, why not just set the flag such that ALL warnings are errors and then use pragma to disable the warnings you consider to be benign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not always an UB.

> If the object being deleted has incomplete class type at the point of deletion and the complete class has a non-trivial destructor or a deallocation function, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Comment: Ahem Exactly my feeling(in comment)! a class with trivial destructor should not cause an UB.

Answer (score 2):

How about if the pointer is `0` (or `nullptr` in C++11)? `delete 0;` is by definition a no-op.

Comment: Does `0` count as an Incomplete type?

Comment: @Als: No, but `struct s; s* p = 0; delete p;` does. I just wanted to emphasize that it's the same as `delete 0;`.

Comment: Ah okay..Ofcourse, This is the borderline case where the type is an Incomplete Opaque pointer but it points to `0`, so `delete`ing it is an No-Op.

Comment: @Als: See my linked question in the comment to the OP, there seems to be some controversity. :) *Edit*: Just saw you already commented that question when I first asked it, nvm then. :D

Comment: Yes AFAIU, deleting a pointer of the type `void*` is an UB,but your in example, `p` has an type `struct` and not `void*`, so it is an legitimate borderline case.