# C++ programming - is this allocation an unavoidable memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I have a doubt related to the pasted code.
I have allocated memory for an int and deleted(as usual).
But somewhere i see this sysntax(line 1) which allocates an anonymous int space.
How to free this space, isn't this result in memory leak?

```
main(){
  int *p = new int;
  new int;

  if(p)
   delete p;
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do not need to check `if(p)`. `delete` can handle `NULL` pointers.

Comment: my doubt is it frees the memory which was allocated for p, but what about the memory allocated in "new int" or "new int" doesn't allocate any memory?

Comment: You do not store the pointer, so you cannot free it. It's not unavoidable, if you store the pointer.

Comment: Since the allocation is pointless, a memory leak is easily avoided by removing that line.

Comment: Let's see... if you leak memory on purpose then it is unavoidable as far as the language is concerned(imho). The compiler could realise that it is pointless and optimize it away however.

Answer (score 14):

If you allocate memory, and deliberately choose not to hold a pointer to it, then you cannot free it.

C++ gives you enough rope to hang yourself with, and allows you to aim a gun at your own foot.
That is nothing new.

---

The other mistake is checking the value of `p` to see if it was allocated successfully.
Only on older compilers does `new` return `NULL` if it fails.  On newer compilers, a failed `new` will result in throwing a `std::bad_alloc` exception.

So in this code, (assuming you are using a compiler from the last decade) you *know* that either:

- the `new` succeeded, and `p` is valid/non-NULL.
- *or* an exception was thrown.

There is no way for `p` to end up `NULL`!

Even if `p` could end up NULL, calling `delete` on a `NULL` value is perfectly safe, and there is nothing wrong with it.

So your example code could well be:

```
int main()
{
  int *p = new int;  // Will throw exception if fails

  new int;           // Deliberate Mem Leak

  delete p;          // No need to check NULL
  system("PAUSE");   // Pause to see results (NOTE: this is skipped if an exception is thrown!)
  return 0;         
}
```

Comment: i am not sure though, but i have read somewhere that deleting a null or un-allocated space is an undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user3312772 deleting a null pointer should not result in undefined behaviour I believe

Comment: @user3312772 `delete NULL;` is well defined.  See [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6177338/311966) or [docs for operator delete](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20delete[]/) for details.  Deleting a non-NULL address that you didn't allocate would indeed result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: yeah my bad, deleting NULL is safe indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is C++, so `unavoidable` is a (slight) overstatement.

"All" you need to to is replace global `operator new`, and have that keep track of allocations.
Now: I can't imagine doing this is real code, but doing the equivalent for class types only is something done in practice (although I don't imply that it's *best* practice!)

For example, this (otherwise quite silly) code does not leak .

```
int count = 0;
void* operator new (size_t size)throw(std::bad_alloc)
{
    if (size == sizeof(int))
    {
        ++count;
        if (count == 2)
            return &count;
    }
    return malloc (size);
}

void operator delete (void *p)throw()
{
    if (p != &count)
        free(p);
}

int main()
{
    int *p = new int;
    new int;
    delete p;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: from this code you mean to say...you will not allocate space for second line (new int)....right?

Comment: well, not allocate any heap, but still return the address of some pre-allocated storage for an int. That is not important; the key thing is that you can take total control of allocation and deallocation. For example, you _can_ (but please don't) implement your own garbage collection.