# Getting the size of the object void* is pointing to

Tags: c++, sizeof, void-pointers

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MemoryLeakTest
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( MemoryLeakTest)
{
    double* n1 = new double(100);
    void* v1 = n1;
    cout << sizeof(v1) << endl;
    delete v1;
}
```

This code will work perfectly fine without any error leaks. But I would like to be able to get the size of the object `void*` is holding on to.I would imagine there is a way because the delete statement knew how large the object v1 was pointing to so that it can delete it so it must be stored some where.

Comment: Short answer: You can't. You need to keep track of the size yourself.

Comment: It is stored "somewhere" - and it's completely opaque to you.  Deliberately so. If you want to know the size, you need to track it yourself.

Comment: Applying `delete` to a `void *` pointer has always been illegal in C++. Your code is not even supposed to compile. (Although to my great surprise Comeau Online compiler accepts `delete` on `void *`.)

Comment: @AndreyT probably has the right answer here; I do get a warning from `clang`.  I'm not a C++ expert at all, so I can't directly confirm or rebut.

Comment: @Caesar - This code doesn't really work according to the language, it is just that *seems to work* is one possible outcome of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying `delete` to a `void *` pointer in C++ is illegal.

If your compiler supports this as a non-standard extension, then most likely `delete` assumes that the unknown object pointed by that pointer has trivial destructor. In that case `delete` does not have to do anything besides immediately handing over the control to the raw-memory deallocation function `::operator delete`, which probably just calls `free`. (This last bit, of course, can depend on the implementation).

So, your question basically boils down to "how to determine the size of `malloc`-ed memory block". There's no standard features that can do that. Either memorize the size yourself, when you allocate it. Or use the non-standard implementation-specific library features, if any such features are provided by your platform.

In some implementations this can be done through `msize` function. But again, in order to do it meaningfully, you'd have to research your implementation first. You need to figure out how the memory is allocated by `new` and/or what exactly `delete v1` does, since it is not standard C++.

Answer (score 0):

The size of `void *` will continue to be `sizeof` a pointer. If you want to find out actual size of the object that the `void *` is pointing to, you should know the actual object and typecast the pointer to the right type. And no, delete will not know the object pointer size and will result in a leak. The right thing to do, even for `delete` is to make sure you typecast the pointer to the right type.

Comment: I just ran the program and I had no leaks.

Running 1 test case...
4

*** No errors detected
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Not sure what the test case is in this case. Are you running a test suite to detect memory leaks via valgrind or such?

Comment: @Gangadhar Using BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE which would notify me if it finds a leak.

Comment: @CarlNorum, I didn't know that. As mentioned elsewhere on SO http://stackoverflow.com/a/941953/334642, deleting a void* won't call the destructors and can potentially result in a leak. That is what I meant by a leak.

Comment: @Gangadhar, that's true if you're deleting an object, but in this case the OP has allocated a `double`, which *has* no destructors.

Comment: @CarlNorum - ack that ! My bad. Should have been a bit more careful when responding. Caesar - there is no memory leak, since you are deleting a basic type. But, it is generally a good practice to ensure you don't delete void* since you might not know the object that the pointer will get pointed to.

Comment: @CarlNorum That still doesn't answer my question. Let put the destructor aside and just worry about getting the size of the object.

Comment: @Caesar, you can't.  Several other people have said that too.

Answer (score 0):

When doing the cast from `double *` to `void *` you are throwing away information for the compiler to work on.

Therefore the compiler does not know what destructos to call or the size of the object.