# Deleting void pointer after assigning it with original type

Tags: c++, void-pointers

Is it ok to delete the void pointer in the below program.

```
class Sample
{
    public:
        int intVal;
        float floatVal;
};

main() {
    Sample *samObj = new Sample();
    void *vPtr = samObj;
    delete vPtr;
}
```

This is just a sample program I have written. Actually, in my project I have no other way than doing similar thing. This similar code is in .h interface file, and when I include this file and compile the other components, compiler gives a warning message as "warning: deleting 'void*' is undefined", But my doubt is since I have assigned the void pointer with the Sample object type, isn't it safe to delete this pointer?

Comment: Might find an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941832/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-void-pointer

Comment: In your example code, you aren't deleting `vPtr`, you are deleting `samObj`, which is fine.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? As soon as you delete `samObj`, `vPtr` is useless since you've effectively deleted that as well.

Comment: Sorry!!! the code shoud be, "delete vPtr"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling delete on a void pointer is **undefined behavior**<sup>[Ref ]</sup>. You should not do it at all. You are not calling `delete` on a void pointer but on pointer of type `Sample` which is fine.

[Ref ]
**C++ Standard :section 5.3.5/3:**

> In the first alternative (delete
>   object), if the static type of the
>   operand is different from its dynamic
>   type, the static type shall be a base
>   class of the operand’s dynamic type
>   and the static type shall have a
>   virtual destructor or the behavior is
>   undefined.  In the second alternative
>   (delete array) if the dynamic type of
>   the object to be deleted differs from
>   its static type, the behavior is
>   undefined.

footnote:

> This implies that an object cannot be
>   deleted using a pointer of type void*
>   because there are no objects of type
>   void

Comment: Thank you Alok... I have to find a alternative way. Acutally the problem in my project is pretty tricky. I have a thread, which takes void * argument, So, the user can pass any type he wish to the thread. He will jst start the thread and forgot it. Now, i have to take care to delete the allocated memory from the user, but the problem is he can pass any type of argument. Not sure, how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not safe to delete a void pointer that way. How is the compiler supposed to 'know' what vPtr points to? Compiler CANNOT; the run time could, but it does not.

Why would the compiler need to 'know' what the vPtr points to? To call the destructors AND to know how much memory to deallocate. Potentially how much memory to deallocate is not such a big problem if the compiler keeps a standard header with each allocation. But I guess that is a detail left to the compiler, so even in this department the result would be 'undefined'.

Comment: The title is misleading.  look at the code; the OP is calling `delete` on a `Sample*`, which is fine.  I don't know if that is a typo or what, but there is nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: I see your point; yes the delete is actually NOT on the void pointer at all. The compiler should NOT complain at all.

Comment: Sorry!! its a type (a very big typo :))... It should be "delete vPtr". I am finding the way to edit the question. I m new to Stackoverflow

Comment: @Santosh: No problem, I took care of it for you.  There is an edit button at the bottom of your post.

Answer (score 0):

The code appears alright.
As long as you remeber to point `void *vPtr` to null or whatever exists.

Real problem comes when you delete `void *vPtr`, as compiler don't what object you are delete, it have no idea about how many memory can be release.