# Delete void* pointer in c++

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I'm reading thinking in c++, chapter 13: dynamic object creation.
In this chapter, Eckel talk about deleting void* may be probably a bug.
The following paragraph confuses me.

> The other memory leak issue has to do with making sure that delete is
>   actually called  for each object pointer held in the container. The
>   container cannot "own" the pointer because it holds it as a void* and
>   thus cannot perform the proper cleanup. The user must be responsible
>   for cleaning up the objects. This produces a serious problem if you
>   add pointers to objects created on the stack and objects created on
>   the heap to the same container because a delete-expression is unsafe
>   for a pointer that hasn't been allocated on the heap.

Can anyone explains more detail why "adding pointers to objects created on the stack and objects created on the heap to the same container" produces a serious problem?

To make the problem more clearly, I add the related code snippet.

```
class Stack {
  struct Link {
    void* data;
    Link* next;
    void initialize(void* dat, Link* nxt);
  }* head;
public:
  void initialize();
  void push(void* dat);
  void* peek();
  void* pop();
  void cleanup();
};
```

Comment: I believe you misread the meanings.  It's stating that you can't delete a `void *` to a non-trivial object **and separately** stating that you can't delete pointers that may point to the stack.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to delete a void pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941832/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-void-pointer)

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule objects on the stack dont need to be Deleted, objects on the heap need. If you place them in the same container how do you keep track of which ones to delete? You better have two containers, one for objects on the stack(the ones that dont need delete), other for objects on the heap(the ones that need to be deleted).

Comment: Or better yet, let the container handle the allocation for you so that you don't need to call delete manually - RAII.

Answer (score 1):

This paragraph is indeed a bit vague. It mixes 2 different issues and that leads to confusion, in my opinion.

1. In order to correctly delete an object, its type must be known to the compiler. For `void*` the type isn't known (that's exactly the point of using `void*` - to hide the actual type). So the deletion can't be performed on such object without casting to the proper actual type.
2. Normally usage of `void*` implies that ownership of the pointed object belongs to some outer entity **by design**, and not to the entity containing the pointer. Inside the entity the pointer is opaque and serves as a handler to an external object, which is a black-box as far as the the entity is concerned. The `Stack` class must be well aware of the responsibilities division and must not attempt to destroy the `void*` object since it has no idea neither about it's lifetime (leading to attempt to free stack variable, for example), nor about the operations that should be done upon the destruction (leading to functional incorrectness).