# deleting a void pointer using delete operator

Tags: c++, void-pointers

whats wrong with the code. What it should be. As it is throwing an error. Operator 'delete', applied to void* argument.

```
int i;
void *ptr = &i;

delete ptr;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941832/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-void-pointer

Comment: `throw` is usually used in the context of runtime. You're talking about the compiler reporting an error with your code.

Comment: @PeterWood: The above code probably compiles fine...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: The original code wouldn't compile; I would hope this version would give a warning (which should help to explain the runtime error).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: yes, you're right ;)

Comment: This is your second question about the same topic. What are you trying to achieve? Because you clearly are doing it in a wrong way.

Answer (score 7):

> whats wrong with the code.

Everything except `int i;`

The second line attempts to convert an integer to a pointer. In special circumstances, you could force that past the compiler with `reinterpret_cast`; but the program would only behave correctly if the integer somehow contained a valid pointer value. (**UPDATE**: the question has now been edited to take the address of `i` instead; so this line is no longer wrong).

The third line attempts to delete invalid memory using an invalid pointer type.

> What it should be.

Something else. Without knowing what you want to do, it's impossible to say. Perhaps you want:

```
int i;
void * ptr = &i;  // Points to `i`, losing type information.
```

> Operator `delete`, applied to `void*` argument.

That's always wrong. You must only `delete` an object you previously allocated with `new`; and the pointer must be to the correct type.

<sub>(or to a base class, if it's a class type with a virtual destructor)</sub>

So the following would be correct; but pointless unless you have a good reason for dynamic allocation:

```
int * ptr = new int;
delete ptr;
```

And of course, if you're writing code that should be robust against memory leaks and runtime errors, you should manage all dynamic memory using [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) types such as containers and smart pointers. So, if you need to a dynamic object, you should do:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr(new int);
```

if you want a to delete it at the end of the current scope or move it into another scope; or

```
auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>();
```

if you want to share ownership between more than one scope. In either case, the pointers will delete the object automatically once you've finished with it.

Comment: int *i = new int; void *ptr = i; delete ptr; Is this ok ?

Comment: @Anand: No, because you must use `int*` to delete an `int`. Without the correct type information, `delete` gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: then in this case how to delete ptr ?

Comment: @Anand: Either `delete i` or `delete static_cast<int*>(ptr)`. But you really shouldn't be messing around with manual deletion in the first place; and certainly shouldn't be using `void*` to manage dynamic resources.

Comment: What an excellent answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

You should only delete things that you allocated with new.

Comment: Absolutely true, but that is not the reason for the error message.

Comment: Yes, since you cannot allocate a pointer of type void with new you also cannot 'delete' it.

Comment: You can. Just change that code to `int* i = new int; void* ptr = i;`. `ptr` now points to an object created with `new`, but you cannot delete it because of its type.

Comment: But you didn't *allocate a pointer of type void*, you allocated one of the type int and assigned it to a void pointer what is actually possible.

Comment: If `Derived` inherits from `Base` and they have virtual destructors, `Derived* i = new Derived; Base* ptr = i; delete ptr;` is perfectly legal. You cannot delete a `void*` because `void` is not a type, that's all.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The only thing I wanted to say is that it is also not legal to use new like so: `void *ptr = new void`. But to the question above your answer is absolutely correct. Sorry if I confused anyone by throwing in memory allocation although it was a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Very naughty code indeed;

1. You're not taking the address of i; use `void* ptr = &i`
   instead. You're compiler is extremely lenient to emit your code.
2. You're deleting from the stack. Not good. You can only `delete`
   things you've `new`ed
3. The compiler doesn't know how much memory to delete if you
   pass `void*` as all the `sizeof` data are lost.

Answer (score 0):

your code will not work because you're trying to delete something which wasn't dynamically allocated.
Anyway deleting void pointers is undefined, see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941832/is-it-safe-to-delete-a-void-pointer) for more info

Comment: the link you have mentioned does not answer my question.

    int *i = new int;
    void *ptr = i;
    delete ptr;

Is this ok ?

Comment: @Anand It answers your question pretty well. Look at the second answer.