# Destructor not invoked when deleting void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, containers, destruction

I've got 3 classes

```
class A
{
    A();
    virtual ~A();
}
class B : public A
{
    B();
    ~B();
}
class C
{
    void *obj;
    C() : obj(nullptr) {}
    ~C() { if (obj) delete obj; }
}
```

when I use class `C` as a container for any child of class `A` and try to delete `C` instance. `A`, `B` destructor is not inveked is it normal? What is the solutuon?

```
C* instance = new C();
instance.obj = new B();
//Magic
delete instance; // A and B destructor is not called
```

Comment: `delete` is very type-aware. If you `delete` a `void *` it wouldn't know the object was originally `C`.

Comment: If you are using `C` as a container for "any child of class `A`", why can't you use `A *` for the type of `obj`?

Comment: You [can't delete a void pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18683731/596781). It' s not valid C++ and it shouldn't even compile. If it does, you're not using a real C++ compiler, and this question is not tagged appropriately.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's not ill-formed to delete `void*`; just undefined behaviour if it isn't null. My (reasonably "real") compiler just gives a warning.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yes, that's better. But this is one of those warnings that you really must not ignore. It's arguably also a bit of legacy cruft in the standard. Why allow a void pointer if the only allowed value is NULL? Might as well scrap the entire thing. You can still permit `delete nullptr`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deleting a pointer to an incompatible type (including `void`) gives undefined behaviour.

> What is the solution?

- use the correct type: either the type you specified with `new`, or a base class if it has a virtual destructor; or
- use `std::shared_ptr<void>`, initialised from `std::shared_ptr<correct_type>`: its deleter will do the right thing.

In this case, it looks like you can simply store `A*` rather than `void*`, since you say it should be "a container for any child of class `A`".

By the way, there's no need to check whether the pointer is null before deleting it.

Comment: +1 for the `shared_ptr<void>`. Very nice. (Can probably also be initialized from a `unique_ptr<T>`.)

Answer (score 6):

You delete a `void*`, so `delete` doesn't know that it's a `B*` so the destructor can't be called. You have to use a class pointer if you want the destructor to be called on deletion.

For example, is all classes that may be C's `obj` extend A, then use an `A*`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *delete* needs the specific type.